Can this happen in a ring with multiplicative identity?
I read a theorem and the proof in the textbook.
"Let $R$ be a ring with multiplicative identity $i$. Let $b_n=ni=i+i+\cdots+i$ for $n$ summands. If $b_n\neq0$ for all positive integer $n$, then $R$ has characteristic $0$.
Proof: If $ni\neq0 $ for all positive integer $n$, then surely we cannot have $na=0$ for some positive integer $n$, for all nonzero $a\in R$, so the characteristic is $0$."
My question:
Can it exist some $a\in R\land a\neq0$ such that the cyclic group $\langle a\rangle$ has a finite order?
My thought:
If $|a|$ is finite, then it means there exists some positive integer $k$ such that $ka=a+a+\cdots+a=0$, so we have $a(i+i+\cdots+i)=a(ki)=ab_k=0$. I hope to conclude $b_k=0$, but I couldn't exclude there might be some zero-divisor in this ring.

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. Then $i=(1,1)$ satisfies $ni=0\iff n=0$, but $a=(0,x)$ satisfies $na=0$ for all $x$.

thank you, does that mean the textbook is wrong? I add the textbook content to this post. @ArturoMagidin

No, the textbook is not wrong. Read the definition of "characteristic". To say $R$ has characteristic $0$ means that for every $n\gt 0$ there exists an $a\in R$ such that $na\neq 0$. It doesn't prevent some $a\neq 0$ from satisfying $na=0$. And your edit removed the hypotheses from your question. Now it is unintelligle, as you put no conditions on $R$.

The reason why if $b_n\neq 0$ implies that you cannot have $na=0$ for all nonzero $a$ is that your hypothesis tells you that taking $a=i$ will exhibit a nonzero $a$ with $na\neq 0$. The statements is not "for every nonzero $a$, $na\neq 0$." The statement is "it is not true that for every nonzero $a$ we have $na=0$." The negation of "for every $a\neq 0$, $na=0$" is not "for every $a\neq 0$, $na\neq 0$." The negation is "there exists at least one $a\neq 0$ such that $na\neq 0$."

Yes, I just carefully read it and see it now, sorry for the silly question :) @ArturoMagidin

Which book are you referring to?

Fraleigh @Shaun
